# AltBeacon Library - reduce bluetooth scan period

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am using AltBeacon Library and trying to detect beacons. I want to reduce the time between the scan cycles.

```
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(30000l);
```

As per documentation the above line should set the background scan period to 3 seconds. But, i still see that the scan period is 5 mins (300000 ms). Am i missing anything?

Comment: Is your app looking for beacons every 3 sec in the background now? Because I tried the same but it did not work for me...it still wakes up every 5 min in the background.

Comment: @ParagKadam, it worked at the time of this question. But, i am not sure about it right now, as i am not using beacons in my current app. So i may not be of much help here.

Comment: Could you explain where should you write this command line? I wrote it on create method and didn't change the scan period...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two method calls:

```
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
```

The first call sets how long a bluetooth scan will last, and the second call sets how long there will be between bluetooth scans.  The commands above effectively do a 1.1 second scan every 31.1 seconds.

You should generally set the backgroundScanPeriod to 1100 ms or more, because beacons that advertise exactly once per second have a slight chance of being missed if their transmission is always on the boundary of when you start and stop scanning.